# My SQL query to list dates that have no records

Tags: mysql

I have an online calendar system that I use for tracking my band's gigs - I'd like to construct a query that will display all Fridays and Saturdays that don't currently have a record assigned to them.

eg,

if I have a record in the DB for Friday 23rd Aug and Friday 30th Aug (records being gigs that are booked), what would the query cirteria be to output Saturday 24th Aug (as it has no record)?

`Select * from ['giglist']
where ['gigdate'is in 'friday','saturday']
and ['gigdate' doesn't have a record]`

I will probably set the days of the week as variables so that the user can run the query for any day or selection of days.

Thanks,

Darren

Comment: can you provide your tables? It would be a simple "left join" of `available_days` with `booked days`, where the `booked day` is null.

Comment: Its just the one table 'giglist' that has a record for every date that is booked.

Comment: Either do as dognose suggests (create a utility table), or handle the logic for missing days at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Comment: The trouble is how far into the future do you want this list to extend is not known

Comment: I was thinking of creating a list of all Fridays and Saturdays for this year where the date is greater than today (all queries will be based on the current year) where none of the dates = any of the dates in the table......I guess the 'where' is a sub-query that lists dates that are already booked?

Answer (score 0):

if assuming from your question there is a field gigdate of date type that keeps date information and a seperate record field.

Then query would be,

```
select DAYNAME(gigdate), DAYOFMONTH(gigdate), MONTHNAME(gigdate) from giglist where   
DAYNAME(gigdate) in ('Friday', 'Saturday') and
recordfield is NULL;
```

It's better to use single date type field and just store date only, as mysql has powerful set of date functions to help you out for your needs.

Comment: Thanks - What I'm looking for is a list of all Fridays and Saturdays. This list then needs to exclude the dates that are listed in the giglist table.